# Does having 2 Flickerwisps and an Impact Tremors win me the game?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm just thinking that if I had a [Flickerwisp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flickerwisp) and an [Impact Tremors](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Impact%20Tremors) in play, and I cast another Flickerwisp, would I be able to have the Flickerwisps "flick" each other until my opponents are at 0 life and win me the game? I'm thinking I might be on to something here.

I'm not sure how the "end of turn" ruling affects this, but if it's an issue I guess I can use a [Fiend Hunter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fiend%20Hunter) for this combo, right?

Comment: If you want to use Fiend Hunter for this, you're going to need 3 of them. If you just have 2, the second one will exile the first, and then nothing will happen.

Comment: The Fiend Hunter combo requires four pieces. I am trying to find ones that only require three, and I only managed to find this one: `Impact Tremors + Food Chain + Misthollow Griffin`. This one requires four but I'll post it anyway: `Impact Tremors + Cloudstone Curio + Burning-Tree Emissary + Burning-Tree Emissary`. Purphoros, God of the Forge can act as an additional Impact Tremors to make the combo more consistent. Priest of Gix can also replace Burning-Tree Emissary. Torrent Elemental can replace Misthollow Griffin.

Comment: @Rainbolt Three, with [Kiki-Jiki, Mirror Breaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370534) and [Deceiver Exarch](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376301) instead of two Flickerwisps. This combo has been used in the past with [Warstorm Surge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376581), now Impact Tremors makes it cheaper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the first Flickerwisp will come back at the beginning of your end of turn step. The creature it exiles wouldn't come back until the beginning of the next end of turn since after they wont trigger at the begging of the end step.

Ruling on the card:

> If the permanent that returns to the battlefield has any abilities that trigger at the beginning of the end step, those abilities won't trigger that turn.

It is worth noting that the ruling on the card is just a clarification of the usual "beginning of phase" effects.  Since all beginning of phase effects are put on the stack first, and then are resolved in LIFO order any new "beginning of phase" effects that are put into play don't fire.  The "beginning of the phase" has already ended.

Fiend Hunter will work for this combo, but you would need three of them. We'll call them A, B, and C. The pattern would follow:

- A enters
- B enters, capturing A
- C enters, capturing B, which releases A
- Repeat

Comment: Oh okay, so it's a slow agonizing death then instead of instant 20 damage :D

Comment: You could do the combo with Restoration Angel

Comment: @JonTheMon Restoration Angel targets non-angel's.   I don't see how your proposed combo will work.

Comment: Huh, so it is. I haven't had to deal with that clause before.

Comment: no, the first Flickerwisp will come back at the beginning of the **next** end step, not at the beginning of its' controller's next end step

Comment: @novarg corrected the wording

Answer (score -2):

Having a Heartless Summoning and impact tremors in play will initiate an infinite damage combo with myr retriever. You will of course need 2x myr retrievers so that when the second one dies returning the first one to hand, continue to play your free myr retrievers due to heartless summoning triggering the key card Impact Tremors.

Its not flickerwisp combo rather Heartless/Impact. Others have already explained the flicker combo above which needs more creatures to get going, also another card to add to flicker combo is cloudshift and this new erie return?? Something like that, from the Blessed v Cursed duel decks

Comment: Myr Retriever can't return itself because its death trigger specifies "another".

Comment: Correct, you need two of them but you play it for free. It has the same chance as finding two flickerwisps. I have a deck that runs this combo. I use muddle the mixture to transmute one of the enchantments or myr retriever. I also have mulldrifter which can convoke for 1x U. I also run jarads orders to kick to combo straight away. It does run 12 fetches to make sure we got the mana we need.

Comment: This answer is describing a similar combo. It doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean??? 2x myr retrievers will trigger each other, when the first one dies then play the second returning the first to your hand and so on and so on. They play for free due to heartless summoning and if you have impact tremors or altar of the brood in play it will trigger the ETB each time you play you free myr. Combo explained

Comment: What I mean is that the question is about Flickerwisp, and you didn't explain what happens in that case.

Comment: Oh ok np, yea i read it as Impact Tremors winning the game and Flickerwisp being an engine to trigger the infinite damage.  as others have explained above that combo doesn't work ... exactly. I meant that the chances of gaving 2 flickerwisps is about as likely as having 2 myr retrievers BUT there are plenty of ways to kick off and find 2x myr retrievers in a modern format.

Comment: Petty sure flickerwisp does not win the game hence why Impact Tremors is the key part and why I was providing an alternative using the said KEY card. Anyway MTG is full of sweet lil combos, i decided to play test (just casul multi player fun) 4x flickerwisps 4x banisher priest 4x fiend hunter 4x cloudshift and 4x eldrazi displacer and it is a bit slow but really fun to play